# Man admits guilt but recants it, leading to investigation and legal struggle

Tags: identify-this-movie

**Premise:**

- A man kills his wife, who has been cheating on him.
- Man is arrested by a policeman, with whom the wife had the affair.
- Man admits guilt to the policeman.
- Upon further questioning, the man recants his statement, saying he feared for his life, because the arresting officer had an affair with the victim/wife.
- Man is off the hook.
- Policeman refuses to let it go, and continues investigation.
- The whole movie is mostly a legal struggle.
- Lead actor is strictly speaking the antagonist. We know he is guilty throughout the movie.

**Other notes:**

- At least one actor is an extremely well-known celebrity, but for the life of me...
- The movie is not new. 2000s.
- Movie was live-action, and not animated. In color.
- Country of origin is US, and language spoken is US English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the exact plot of [Fracture](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488120/combined) from 2007.

> Theodore "Ted" Crawford (Anthony Hopkins), a wealthy and talented structural engineer, discovers his wife Jennifer (Embeth Davidtz) is having an affair with police detective Rob Nunally (Billy Burke). Crawford proceeds to shoot his wife, seriously wounding her and he immediately confesses the crime to Nunally on the scene. However, at his arraignment, Crawford retracts his confession.
>
> At the trial, Crawford acts as his own attorney, which serves as a key vehicle for the plot of the movie - matching up against a star prosecutor as a supposedly untrained litigant. Crawford reveals that the arresting officer (Nunally) was having an affair with his wife and was also present during his interrogation. His confession is ruled to be inadmissible as evidence, as it was fruit of the poisonous tree.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: Bingo! Wanted to rewatch this, but it's been so long. Thanks!